# How do I turn off logging for asset requests with thin and sinatra?

Tags: logging, sinatra, thin, sinatra-assetpack

I'm using `sinatra/assetpack` and `thin`. How do I turn off logging the asset requests like [quiet assets](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) for Rails?

Comment: No such feature specifically in `sinatra/assetpack`. You can turn off the logging completely in your Sinatra app but I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: @Kashyap any idea where / how I could intercept logging calls and try to guess if its an asset request?

Comment: Sinatra uses Rack::CommonLogger as the interface for logging. There is a class inside Base.rb named `Sinatra::ComminLogger` which just calls `Rack::CommonLogger` which logs the data on each response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got assets turned off with this:

```
module Sinatra
  module QuietLogger

    @extensions = %w(png gif jpg jpeg woff tff svg eot css js coffee scss)

    class << self
      attr_accessor :extensions

      def registered(app)
        ::Rack::CommonLogger.class_eval <<-PATCH
          alias call_and_log call

          def call(env)
            ext = env['REQUEST_PATH'].split('.').last
            if #{extensions.inspect}.include? ext
              @app.call(env)
            else
              call_and_log(env)
            end
          end
        PATCH
      end
    end

  end
end
```

And then simply register it in the app:

```
configure :development
  register QuietLogger
end
```

Comment: Actually, your solution can be refactored a little bit. Check the [Sinatra-Contrib](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/tree/master/lib/sinatra) project source codes. You may send in a PR with the refactored solution if you want to :)

Comment: I'd be down, no idea how to write specs for it tho

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra's logger is just a subclass of `Rack::CommonLogger`. More importantly, the logger portion is a middleware that gets attached to the Sinatra App. If your have your own implementation of logger based on the `Rack::CommonLogger` module (or your own middleware), that can be added to Sinatra like so:

```
use MyOwnLogger
```

We will subclass `Rack::CommonLogger` and modify the `call` method to ensure logging takes places only if body is data and not an asset.

```
module Sinatra # This need not be used. But namespacing is a good thing.

  class SilentLogger < Rack::CommonLogger

    def call(env)
      status, header, body = @app.call(env)
      began_at = Time.now
      header = Rack::Utils::HeaderHash.new(header) # converts the headers into a neat Hash

      # we will check if body is an asset and will log only if it is not an asset

      unless is_asset?(body)
        body = BodyProxy.new(body) { log(env, status, header, began_at) }
      end

      [status, header, body]

    end

    private

    def is_asset?(body)
      # If it just plain text, it won't respond to #path method
      return false unless body.respond_to?(:path)
      ext = Pathname.new(body.path).extname
      ext =~ /\.png|\.jp(g|eg)|\.js/ ? true : false
    end

  end
end
```

And then, in your app:

```
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    use Sinatra::SilentLogger

  end
```

Comment: I actually don't think this works, because middleware keeps passing `env` through the application stack, and the old sinatra logger is still being used as well!

Comment: I also tried it copy / paste and with setting `env['sinatra.commonlogger']` to no avail

Comment: Yep. Figured out the reason why that happens. `sinatra-assetpack` sends the CSS without creating a file and so, the `path` logic doesn't work. My bad.